# What permissions are required for MS DNS WMI API?

Tags: security, permissions, wmi

My webserver (in a datacenter) runs both IIS and MS-DNS Server and also hosts my website's DNS zone. I've been using `no-ip.org` for a while, but I don't like having to manually update it myself, so I wrote my own replacement and I'd like to use my own DNS Zone too.

I have already written my own MS-DNS Zone editor using [the WMI DNS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it works when I run it under the user account of a member of "Domain Admins" (my server is also part of an Active Directory domain too).

However, running code under an Administrator account is asking for trouble. I would like to know if it's possible to set up an AD Delegations or some other absolute-minimum-permissions setup that would allow my application to update the DNS zone.

I'll note that the DNS Zone in question is stored using a physical zone file and is not stored in Active Directory (the DNS server in question is not a domain controller, so that option is not available).

This question might be better-off on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I spoke too soon. I found this page: http://forums.asp.net/t/589684.aspx/1

There's a poster who provided these instructions:

`Start` > `Run` > `wmimgmt.msc` > `WMI Control` > `Properties` > `Security`

And then I can add my own user account that would have permission to alter DNS and only DNS, nothing else, without needing full administrative rights.

...I think. I haven't verified this. Can anyone let me know if this is correct?